# injecting request scoped bean into @Service of another sub-module of same maven project not working

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, javabeans, autowired

```
package com.x.services.y.common.beans;

@Component
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class DataRequestScope {
private String fname = "first name";
private String lname = "last name";

public String getFname() {
    return fname;
}

public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}

public String getLname() {
    return lname;
}

public void setLname(String lname) {
    this.lname = lname;
}
```

}

And in another component, autowired as

```
package com.x.services.y.service.impl;

@Component("SomeInterface")
public class SomeInterfaceImpl implements SomeInterface {
     @Autowired
     private Provider<DataRequestScope> employeeDetailsProvider;
}
```

DataRequestScope & SomeInterfaceImpl are in different submodules of same maven project.

I get this exception.

```
No matching bean of type [com.x.y.z.common.beans.DataRequestScope] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: Do you a `@componentScan` somewhere ? Is it a Spring Boot project or regular Spring ?

Comment: There is no specific component scan defined. It is a regular spring project.

Comment: Can you provide your configuration class ? Because it seems to me that if you don't properly define the `@ComponentScan` annotation, then your error is logic to me.